# Starting new job in a week, not been told where to go

Tags: new-job

Pretty much as per job title really, I had a conditional offer just over a month ago (subject to referrals, health check etc.), handed in my notice, now just over a week to go until the new job starts, I still haven't heard where they actually want me on my first day! I emailed my new boss on the weekend to ask, it's now Thursday and no reply yet (his out of office was on stating he would be back yesterday), left a voice mail with him earlier as well!

Starting to panic a bit, unnecessarily perhaps?

Comment: Most likely unnecessary, yes. So what's your question?

Comment: "I had a conditional offer just over a month ago". Have they made it unconditional yet? Do you have an actual offer letter?

Comment: Yes you are worried unnecessarily. You don't have to worry about where they want you to come when you are not even sure *if* they want you to come. I suggest you worry about *that* first, and about your original issue second.

Comment: Instead of posting a question here, perhaps it would be better to give them a phone call?

Comment: While I appreciate I'm a being a bit of a Captain Hindsight here, maybe don't give in your notice until referrals and background checks are completed and a firm non-conditional offer given.  I say this more for the benefit of future readers rather than the OP.

Comment: Obligatory [Seinfeld](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBn8XttrSew) [references](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6SaCzKA5MQ)

Answer (score 5):

You have over a week to go yet, so you're probably panicking over nothing.

You'll likely hear from the HR department next week regarding final completion of your checks, and then where to go and what to expect.

If you don't hear by Thursday of next week, call again.

Comment: +1 And ***call***, don't just email.

Answer (score 0):

An offer means nothing until it is a signed contract. Contact them ASAP in order to set a date to sign the final contract. Contact them using a more direct means of communication than e-mail, i.e a phone call.

This way you might keep your present job just in case they tell you they backed out.

Comment: almost guaranteed the OP doesn't know what unconditional/conditional means. The term "conditional job offer" is uncommon, OP probably thinks conditional means unconditional.

Comment: "An offer means nothing until it is a signed contract"

This is not true in every jurisdiction.  In the UK, for example, a contract can be verbal and is just as binding (if harder to prove) than a written contract.  A "contract" is an agreement, not a document.  The terms and conditions of employment is a document.